# Copy Trigger stops row being inserted

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers, linked-server

I am trying to create a trigger that copies newly inserted data from one table and inserts it into another table in a  linked server.
However, when the trigger is created it stops the data appearing in the original table until the trigger is deleted and also does not even copy it over to the other table in the linked server either.

Here is my trigger

```sql
    GO /****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[CopyTMSINFO]    Script Date: 12/07/2022 12:53:29 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CopyTMSINFO]
ON [dbo].[d_iface_att]
After INSERT
AS DECLARE @EmpID nvarchar(MAX),
        @datetime datetime

SELECT @EmpID = ins.emp_id FROM INSERTED ins;
SELECT @datetime = ins.date_and_time FROM INSERTED ins;

INSERT INTO [MAL-HQ-SQL01].[MallaghanApp].[dbo].[EmployeeClockIn] (Id,Employee,TASDateTimeStart,TMSDateTime,JobType)
VALUES ( NEWID(),@EmpID,0,@datetime, 'TMS')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as i dont know much about this stuff and i am really confused.

Comment: Your trigger is fatally flawed; it *assumes* an `INSERT` only ever contains **one row**; this is completely untrue. An `INSERT` can contain 0+ rows. See [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers)

Comment: There are already built tools for various forms of replication. Why are you trying to build this yourself? It's almost always a bad idea to have a trigger access anything outside of its own database, let alone a remote server. All of a sudden, your database availability is affected by the reachability of the remote server, and as you're already experiencing, that may lead to transactions being blocked.

Comment: Try adding `set nocount on;` as the first actual statement in the trigger body. And address the other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your trigger:

- You need to use `SET NOCOUNT ON` to prevent the "rows done" messing up exepcted resultsets in some client drivers.
- You need to take into account multiple (or zero) rows in the `inserted` table.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CopyTMSINFO]
ON [dbo].[d_iface_att]
AFTER INSERT
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
    RETURN;

INSERT INTO [MAL-HQ-SQL01].MallaghanApp.dbo.EmployeeClockIn
  (Id, Employee, TASDateTimeStart, TMSDateTime, JobType)
SELECT
  NEWID(),
  ins.emp_id,
  0,
  ins.date_and_time,
  'TMS'
FROM inserted ins;
```

However, inserting into a linked server using a trigger is *very* bad form anyway. What happens if the remote server is offline?

You should instead use other replication methods, such as the *remote* server pulling data from *this* server using an Agent Job.